# Is the behaviour of Java Cookie.setMaxAge(0) down to implementation or is there a specification?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have a web application running on an old modified Tomcat installation.  In order to delete a session cookie after logout, I have the following code:

```
Cookie sessionCookie = new Cookie("session",null);
sessionCookie.setMaxAge(0);
response.addCookie(sessionCookie);
```

In my web application, I have a problem in that it is returning the current time as the expires portion of the cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: sesssion=null; Expires=Sat, 18-Feb-2012 18:04:52 GMT
```

The problem is it only takes a client's PC to be a little behind the server for it to carry on sending the cookie!

However, in Tomcat 5.5, it returns:

```
Set-Cookie: session=null; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT
```

Which is the more desired behaviour.

My question is are both correct, is there any official guide on how this should be implemented, the documentation just states:

> A zero value causes the cookie to be deleted.

Perhaps I will have to add the Set-Cookie: header myself to get around this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is nothing in the specification very specific about the implementation of that method.

However, you should never rely on cookies being immediately deleted by the browser, you shouldnt even rely to the browser deleting the cookie at all, since from the server you don't have control over the client behavior at all.

What are you storing in that cookie, could you simply use the session already managed by the container?

When you invalidate a Session on the server, even if the cookie stays on the browser it wont matter since it will be invalidated server side and the session ID in the cookie will not match an existing session anymore, and the objects that were bound to that session will be destroyed.

Comment: It's complicated.  It's a proprietary server that has overridden much of the servlet parts and you cannot invalidate the session at all, calling those methods causes errors.  The cookie is the session id and a token for the load balancer.  As it stands now, if the client's clock is wrong, the load balancer refuses the request altogether as "null" isn't in the right format.  However, if I permit it to pass the original session/token, that session has now been marked as logged out and cannot be used for security, so either way those with wrong clocks must restart their browsers!

Comment: @Alan: shouldn't the browser be redirected to the login page?

Comment: @SkipHead it will still use the old Session ID as the server allows us no way to invalidate and create a new session, the only way for the server to generate a new Session ID is if there is no Session passed in the cookie - I inherited this and would never use the server software for any other project.

Comment: @Alan: Wow, that's messed up. My condolences. Sorry I have no constructive help.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will expire a cookie if the expire time <= current time.

If you're doing it manually, most people would return 0 epoch (which is what you're seeing with tomcat 5.5) or at the very least the current time minus some amount of time to account for clock drift. That being said, you can never account for an end user's computer's clock being completely hosed.

Even tomcat 5.5 is old software. It's EOL is September of this year (2012). It sounds like your problem is that you're running an ancient version of tomcat (or java) which hasn't been upgraded or maintained. Occasionally you *do* have to upgrade things.